# How to access deeper levels of JSON Object in PHP

Tags: php, json

Using this below as an example of a JSON response I would get from an API using PHP

```
[
   {
    "profile_background_tile": true,
    "listed_count": 82,
    "status":  {
      "created_at": "Fri Apr 20 20:06:12 +0000 2012",
      "place": null,
    },
    "default_profile": false,
    "created_at": "Tue Oct 25 00:03:17 +0000 2011"
  }
]
```

I would use something like this...

```
$obj = json_decode($json);

foreach($obj as $index => $user) {
    echo $user->profile_background_tile;
    echo $user->listed_count;
    echo $user->status;    
    echo $user->default_profile;
    echo $user->created_at;
}
```

Now where I need some help is in the JSON response under `status` there is `created_at` and `place`

I do not know how to access those items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the exact same logic, but a level deeper:

```
echo $user->status->created_at;
echo $user->status->place;
```

Here is why that works: your decoded JSON is array of objects. Each object has properties like  `profile_background_tile`. They also have a `status` property, which happens to be another object, with properties `created_at` and `place`. And you access object properties with `$obj->prop` syntax.

Comment: That is what I had thought and I thought I had tried that with no success, I will try again

Comment: Ahh it does work, I had tried it in a smaller demo before and it wasn't working but trying it in my main class now works, thanks!

Comment: @CodeDevelopr Don't worry, you don't have to delete the comment. I updated my answer with an explanation, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

### Error

Your `JSON` is not valid ...

Look at

```
"status":  {
  "created_at": "Fri Apr 20 20:06:12 0000 2012",
  "place": null,
},
```

there is `,` after `"place": null`  which should not be there

Try

```
$json = '[{"profile_background_tile": "true",
    "listed_count": 82,
    "status":  {
      "created_at": "Fri Apr 20 20:06:12 0000 2012",
      "place": null
    },
    "default_profile": false,
    "created_at": "Tue Oct 25 00:03:17 +0000 2011"
  }]';

echo "<pre>";
$obj = json_decode ( $json );
foreach ( $obj as $index => $user ) {
    echo $user->status->created_at , PHP_EOL;
    echo $user->status->place , PHP_EOL;

}
```

Output

```
 Fri Apr 20 20:06:12 0000 2012
```